# Reading from file and storing into an array of structs

Tags: c, struct

I have a simple file formatted as such

```
NAME|VALUE
NAME|VALUE
NAME|VALUE
```

I am trying to read these in, and store them in an array of structs, the struct is this

```
struct data
{
    char* name;
    char* value;
};
```

For now, I know the size of the array will be 3, so I did this:

```
struct data pairs[3];
```

Here is my code as I am trying to read it in from the file:

```
char *tempVal;
int i =0;
    if(file != NULL)
        {
            char curLine [128];
            while(fgets(curLine, sizeof curLine, stockFile) != NULL)
            {   

                tempVal = strtok(curLine,"|");
                printf("i:%i\n",i);
                pairs[i].name= tempVal;
                printf("name at pos %i is %s\n",i, pairs[i].name);
                tempVal = strtok(NULL,"|");
                pairs[i].value= tempVal;
                printf("value at pos %i is %s\n",i, pairs[i].value);
                ++i;
            }
            fclose(file);
        }
```

and each of those printf statments prints the correct thing along the way, then I try to print the array with this

```
int j
for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {   

        printf("ENTRY# %i\NAME:%s\VALUE:%s\n\n",j,pairs[j].name, pairs[j].value);
    }
```

Sorry the indentation is a little weird, tried messing with the code blocks but couldn't get it quite perfect. However, I am wondering why it shows the correct thing during the while loop as it goes along, but then after it is complete the for loop shows all three of the array entries having the same name(the value is correct for the third entry but for the first and second entries the value field contains half of the correct value for the third entry)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned from `strtok()` will be pointing to an element in `curLine`, so all entries in the array of `struct`s will be pointing to an element in `curLine` which is overwritten with each call to `fgets()` (and will only be valid for the current iteration).

You should make a copy of the value returned from `strtok()` during the `while`, possibly using `strdup()`:

```
while(fgets(curLine, sizeof curLine, stockFile) != NULL)
{   
    tempVal = strtok(curLine,"|");
    printf("i:%i\n",i);
    pairs[i].name = strdup(tempVal);
    printf("name at pos %i is %s\n",i, pairs[i].name);
    tempVal = strtok(NULL,"|");
    pairs[i].value = strdup(tempVal);
    printf("value at pos %i is %s\n",i, pairs[i].value);
    ++i;
}
```

`free()` them later when no longer required:

```
for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    free(pairs[j].name);
    free(pairs[j].value);
}
```

Comment: Updated answer for `free()`. You need to copy the values so that the pairs in the array are not referencing `curLine`, which is changing with each call to `fgets()`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense because the curLine pointer is changing with each call and I can't have the struct value referencing that pointer. Freeing them will do what exactly?

Comment: `strdup()` allocates memory (using `malloc()`), which must be `free()`d to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: Makes sense, I'm using gcc and when I try to run the program with the for loop at the end to free the memory, it gives me a warning: "incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'free' [enabled by default]"

Comment: Oh, right, thanks. Also, is there any other way to do this with out strdup() ? I am thinking there should be a way to take a copy of the value returned from strtok, store the value not as a pointer and set the to the value in the struct, or am I just confused on how it works?

Comment: An alternative would be to have `data.name` and `data.value` as `char[]` rather than `char*`. BUT, you need to ensure that token returned by `strtok()` is not bigger than the size of `name` and `value` arrays. You could then use `strncpy()` instead of `strdup()`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11271/discussion-between-andrew-and-hmjd)

Comment: That make sense, thank you. Last question, I have the .value member stored as char* and the value is correct now. I want to convert it to a double or float, I tried atof and strtod and both gave me garbage as answers, why and how do I correct that?

Comment: @Andrew, can you post another question for that? Is is different from the title of this question and will attract attentions from other people on SO and would be more useful.

Comment: here is the other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605653/converting-char-to-float-or-double

Comment: are you `free()`ing before using `atof()` and `strtod()`?

Comment: No, I didn't free anything until the end of the program. Is there someway I could use atof/strtod as I read in the file like atof(strdup(..)) but then I don't know when/how I would free it

Comment: see if you can help me with this too, thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607027/reading-from-file-and-using-strtod-program-misses-last-line-in-file