# Converting char* to float or double

Tags: c, strtod, atof

I have a value I read in from a file and is stored as a char*. The value is a monetary number, #.##, ##.##, or ###.##. I want to convert the char* to a number I can use in calculations, I've tried atof and strtod and they just give me garbage numbers. What is the correct way to do this, and why is the way I am doing it wrong?

This is essentially what I am doing, just the char* value is read in from a file. When I print out the temp and ftemp variables they are just garbage, gigantic negative numbers.

Another Edit:

I am running exactly this in gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 char *test = "12.11";
 double temp = strtod(test,NULL);
 float ftemp = atof(test);
 printf("price: %f, %f",temp,ftemp);
 return 0;
```

}

and my output is price: 3344336.000000, 3344336.000000

Edit: Here is my code

```
if(file != NULL)
    {
        char curLine [128];
        while(fgets(curLine, sizeof curLine, file) != NULL)
        {               
            tempVal = strtok(curLine,"|");          
            pairs[i].name= strdup(tempVal);
            tempVal = strtok(NULL,"|");
            pairs[i].value= strdup(tempVal);
            ++i;
        }
        fclose(file);
    }

    double temp = strtod(pairs[0].value,NULL);
    float ftemp = atof(pairs[0].value);
    printf("price: %d, %f",temp,ftemp);
```

my input file is very simple name, value pairs like this:

```
NAME|VALUE
NAME|VALUE
NAME|VALUE
```

with the value being dollar amounts

SOLVED: Thank you all, I was using %d instead of %f and didn't have the right headers included.

Comment: The problem must be somewhere else, the code you posted is perfectly valid and working. Please show us how you read your file.

Comment: 1. `atof` returns `double` as well: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/atof.html

Comment: 2. `%d` is for integers. Use `%f`.

Comment: 3. You forgot `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are missing an include :
`#include <stdlib.h>`, so GCC creates an implicit declaration of `atof` and `atod`, leading to garbage values.

And the format specifier for double is `%f`, not `%d` (that is for integers).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char *test = "12.11";
  double temp = strtod(test,NULL);
  float ftemp = atof(test);
  printf("price: %f, %f",temp,ftemp);
  return 0;
}
/* Output */
price: 12.110000, 12.110000
```

Comment: +1. Right. This is the problem. [before OPs edits, there were actually three problems]

Answer (score 1):

Code posted by you is correct and should have worked. But check exactly what you have in the `char*`. If the correct value is to big to be represented, functions will return a positive or negative `HUGE_VAL`. Check what you have in the `char*` against maximum values that `float` and `double` can represent on your computer.

Check [this page for `strtod` reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtod/) and [this page for `atof` reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atof/).

I have tried the example you provided in both Windows and Linux and it worked fine.

Comment: According to: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/atof.html (which is aligned with the C standard): "If the value cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: The values are all much smaller than the max either variable type can represent, the largest value I have is 120.55.

Comment: @George: don't use cplusplus.com. It's full of errors. Neither `atof` nor `strtod` return HUGE_VAL in case of an overflow. According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atof), the return value is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("price: %d, %f",temp,ftemp); 
              ^^^
```

This is your problem.  Since the arguments are type `double` and `float`, you should be using `%f` for both (since `printf` is a variadic function, `ftemp` will be promoted to `double`).

`%d` expects the corresponding argument to be type `int`, not `double`.

Variadic functions like `printf` don't really know the types of the arguments in the variable argument list; you have to tell it with the conversion specifier.  Since you told `printf` that the first argument is supposed to be an `int`, printf will take the next `sizeof (int)` bytes from the argument list and interpret it as an integer value; hence the first garbage number.

Now, it's almost guaranteed that `sizeof (int)` < `sizeof (double)`, so when `printf` takes the next `sizeof (double)` bytes from the argument list, it's probably starting with the middle byte of `temp`, rather than the first byte of `ftemp`; hence the second garbage number.

Use `%f` for both.