# C++ String to float with precision

Tags: c++, string, file

I have a file with number readings (example 5.513208E-05 / 1.146383E-05)
I read the file and store the entries in a temporary string.
After that I convert the temporary string into float variable (which I store in an Multi Dimensional Array).
I use the code below to convert.

```
getline(infile, temporary_string, ',');

Array[i][0] = ::atof(temporary_string.c_str());

getline(infile, temporary_string);

Array[i][1] = ::atof(temporary_string.c_str());
```

The problem is that when I print the floats to the screen

5.51321e-05  1.14638e-05    instead of 
5.513208E-05 1.146383E-05

How can I get the precise numbers stored ???

Comment: What's the variable type of `Array`? If it's float, try changing it to double.

Comment: Ehm, `float` will give you approximately log10(2^23) digits, which is "6.92", so between 6 and 7 digits.

Comment: follow  this link may help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605653/converting-char-to-float-or-double

Comment: Floats are not precise. Six significant figures of precision is about normal for `float` on a 32-bit system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't specify precision when you read or convert the string. Instead you set the precision when you output the value:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << 1.2345 << '\n';
```

The above will produce the following oputput:

```
1.23
```

See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Comment: Thank you ... the precision was fine, it was the cout that was rounding it up

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have `double Array[][]`, not `float`. A text presentation (base 10) is always approximated by the binary floating point number (base 2), but with luck approximated number of atof has the same presentation, when using the same format. In general one does not do much calculation, and on output uses a reduced precision with setprecision or formats.

Answer (score 0):

Every floating-point representation of numbers has limited precision.  In particular, `float` has 24 bits (1 fixed+23 variable) for its binary mantissa, thus implying a precision of roughly seven decimal digits.

If you need more precision for the stored number, you may wish to consider using `double` instead of `float`.  On normal PCs, `double` has 53 bits (1+52) for the binary mantissa, thus allowing a 15-decimal digit precision.

But remember that there's also a problem when those numbers are output.  I think the default precision for both `printf`() and `std::ostream` is only 6 digits, both for `float` and for `double`, unless you specify otherwise.  There is no point, however, in demanding a higher precision during output than what the data type provides.  So, even though you *can* say `printf("%0.30g", some_float)`, the extra 23 digits beyond the seven actually supported by the data type might not really produce useful information.