# converting string to double in c

Tags: c, string, type-conversion

I am having a problem converting string to a double. Please help me out.

Here's my code:

```
char Price[100];
double newPrice;
printf("\nPlease enter the price:");
fgets(Price,100,stdin);
newPrice = atof  (Price);
printf("\nPrice of item is %f",newPrice);
```

It gives diff output while running with diff files.

file1 (method 1):

```
char   Price[100];
double newPrice;

int main()
{
    myval();
    return 0;
}

myval()
{
    printf("\nPlease enter the price:");
    fgets(Price, 100, stdin);

    newPrice = atof(Price);
    printf("\nPrice of item is %f", newPrice);  
}
```

file2 (method 2)

```
#define MAX 50

char    oldPrice[MAX];
double  newPrice;

int main()
{
    UserInput(); 
}

int UserInput()
{
    printf("\nPlease enter the price:");
    fgets(oldPrice, MAX, stdin);

    newPrice = atof(oldPrice);
    printf("\nPrice of item is %f", newPrice);  

    return 0;
}
```

The above two methods were compiled using tcc(tiny Compiler). Both methods are the same , but i get a diff output for these 2.
output 1:

```
D:\>new.exe

Please enter the price:12.3

Price of item is 12.300000
```

Output 2:

```
D:\>t.exe

Please enter the price:12.3

Price of item is 7735248.000000
```

Comment: Technically there's no difference between the two functions (except the undefined behavior by not returning something from the `myval` function in the first example). Are you sure you build the second example with the shown code before trying it?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - I don't currently understand it, but [repro on ideone](http://ideone.com/PBG2K1)

Comment: Ah, although [the first one also fails](http://ideone.com/U8JUnd). Although I still don't know _why_.

Comment: I can reproduce the behaviour if I don't include `<stdlib.h>` for `atof`. That seems to be the real difference between the two code snippets above, from which the include directives were, er, excluded.

Comment: @MOehm - huh. Yes. So... what's being picked up for `atof` when it's not included, I wonder?

Comment: @Chowlett: In C89, C silently assumes `int` as return value. In C99, this shouldn't compile without prototype. (When I define a double of value 12.3 and do some pointer nastiness to get an int which then is print-effed with `"%f"`, I can reproduce the original result on my machine.)

Comment: Thank You @MOehm i got the correct answer by including the lib file(stdlib.h).

Answer (score 1):

You must include `<stdlib.h>` to get the right prototype for `atof`:

```
double atof(const char *);
```

With that, the behaviour is as expected. (I reckon that you included it for the first snippet, but not for the second.)

The compiler should warn you about using a function without prototype. Using a function without prototype is legal in C89, but the compiler will assume that the return value is `int`. That and printig the value with type-unaware `printf` seems to lead to the strange output.

In C99 and newer standards, it is illegal to use a function without prototype. So I recommend to use at least C99 if your compiler supports it. As a minimum, turn on compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a include in your file.

```
#include < stdlib.h >
```

See also
[Converting char* to float or double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605653/converting-char-to-float-or-double)

Comment: Thank You.. I got the answer by including lib file