# char *argv[] to floating point type casting in plain C

Tags: c, types, casting

I am trying to convert argv[1] to a floating point value but I end up with an compilation error. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

        double circleArea = 3.14159 * atof(argv[1]) * atof(argv[1]); //this works

        double circleArea = 3.14159 * (double) argv[1] * (double) argv[1]; //this does not

        return 0;

}`
```

Why does the first statement compile and the second one does not? Should not the `(double) argv[1]` be just as valid as `atof(argv[1])`? I want to be able to do this in plain C not C++.

Update: These are the errors I get:

```
circleArea.c: In function ‘main’:
circleArea.c:9:2: error: pointer value used where a floating point value was expected
  double area = 3.14159 * (double) argv[1] * (double) argv[1]; //this does not
  ^~~~~~
circleArea.c:9:2: error: pointer value used where a floating point value was expected
```

Comment: `argv[1]` is a `char*`, and casting a `char*` to a `double` doesn't make sense. _Casting_ is not the same thing as _converting_

Comment: @MichaelWalz - actually a cast is a type of conversion.    The issue here is that converting a `char *` to a `float` (or `double`) is not the same as interpreting and parsing a string to obtain a `float`.   The latter is what `atof()` does.

Comment: @Peter yes, that's a better explanation.

Comment: @MichaelWalz - I thought so too  ;)

Comment: This is a plain C question not a C/C++ question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing is related to cast/conversion. In the second line - where you are getting error - you need to convert the string to `double`, but you are not - you are just casting the value, i.e. "telling the compiler that what you have there is a `double`", which is not.

Casting works in C for similar types - `int` to `float`, `short` to `double`, `float` to `long`, `char` to `int`. Of course, you might lose precision in some of the conversions there. However, you can't, for instance, convert a `int []` to `int` (actually, you might, but you certainly have unexpected results) because one is an array and the other is a single variable.

To make it work, you should use `atod` function. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605653/converting-char-to-float-or-double) for details.